# List<HashMap> list = new ArrayList<>(); In java

Tags: java, hashmap

In java, Is this wrong ? Whenever I tried to add something my old value is replaced with new value. Is it not possible to store data in list of hashmap like below statement?
When I store data as string
List list = new ArrayList<>();
like this.. it is working properly but when I tried to write hashmap in generic it is not returning old data..
I need your advice.

```
List<HashMap> dataArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
LinkedHashMap<String, String> hashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for (int j = 0; j < name.length; j++) {
    System.out.print("Enter " + name[j] + ":");
    storedata[j] = scanner.next();
    hashMap.put(name[j], storedata[j]);
}

dataArrayList.add(hashMap);
```

Comment: "*when I tried to write hashmap in generic it is not returning old data*" Generics do not change runtime behaviour, so this cannot possibly be accurate.

Comment: The only way this can override entries in the map is if the array called `name` contains duplicates. You haven't shown where that's declared.

Comment: @Michael Thanks! for helping Sir, 
Actually [ {FirstName: Name1 , Age: 51 } , {FirstName: Name2 , Age: 99 } ] <- I want output like this, so maybe my key (FirstName, Age) are the same all the time, therefore it is overriding, isn't it..
So how to add this kind of data to the list?

Comment: as per above comment. You need to create class say "User" with properties firstName,Age... And create a list<User>. This is the standard way to do things in java. Each user object are unique users. Try not to be so much generic. The HashMap impl also work but you need to create that many hashmap object which is not a good/standard way.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code snippet provided the values in hashMap will only get updated in case there are duplicates in your name array. I am not getting why you are creating a List of hashmap as you are only adding one hashmap in the list.

I think what you are trying to say is as below
name array ={tom, jerry, tom, jerry, duck}
storedata array ={d1, d2, d3, d4, d5}

output : {[tom,{d1,d3}],[jerry,{d2,d4}],[duck,{d5}]}

So if you want something like this then create a HashMap as below

```
LinkedHashMap<String,List<String>> hashMap=new LinkedHashMap<>();
for (int j = 0; j < name.length; j++) {
    System.out.print("Enter " + name[j] + ":");
    storedata[j] = scanner.next();
    if(!hashMap.containsKey(name[j])
       hashMap.put(name[j],new ArrayList<>());
    hashMap.put(name[j],storedata[j]);
}
System.out.println(hashMap);
```